# Purpose of "default" keyword in "export default object" in react, cant we avoid writting "default" keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, default, keyword

while exporting components in react we use "export default objectName", why cant we just write "export objectName" without default keyword ?

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (



);
}
}

export  App;

Comment: The correct syntax would be `export class App extends Component {}` or `class App extends Compontent {}; export { App }`. And of course that'll create a named export which you have to import differently.

Comment: So basically it is a syntax, that we should follow, correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct syntax.